# Extract new cookies after login with urllib2

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2

I ran into a problem which I can not solve. I am able to successfully get the cookies and use them after the login to a web application. The problem is that the web application sets new cookies after a couple of clicks which I need to have.

How do I extract, or get the additional, cookies after the login? Here is my code so far:

```
  def _login_to_page(self,url):
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    cookiehandler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)
    proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"https" : self._proxy})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookiehandler, proxy_support)
    try:
      login_post_data = {'op':'login','user':self._username,'passwd':self._password,'api_type':'json'}
      response = opener.open(str(self._path_to_login_url), urllib.urlencode(login_post_data), self._request_timeout).read()
      if response: 
        print "[+] Login successful"
        self._login_cookies = cj 
      else:
        "[-] Login has probably failed. Wrong Credentials?"

 def get_url_loggedin(self,url):
    #the variable self._login_cookies are the cookies from the previous login
    cookiehandler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self._login_cookies)
    proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : self._proxy})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookiehandler, proxy_support)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    try:
      url_response = opener.open(url, None, self._request_timeout).read()
    except Exception,e:
      print "[-] Could not read page: "
      print "[??] Error: " +repr(e)
```

Sorry if my English is a bit weird I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Your English is pretty good so don't worry about it! One question: What is the problem you're having with your current code? And an observation: You probably shouldn't be catching all exceptions. It's usually better to catch only the ones that _might_ be raised and then only if you have something you want to do with them.

Comment: Umm, I fail to see extraction of cookies in your code, rather than you're using previously extracted `self._login_cookies` ones. How do you extract those and why can't you use the same method in another place? :)

Comment: wow this was fast guys! :) Here is the previous code for extracting the cookie:

Comment: Just edit your post adding another snippet, don't paste code in comments.

Comment: My semi-educated guess in this case would be that your `CookieJar` will contain new cookies after they are sent, if you set the same reference of `_login_cookies` while doing other requests.

Comment: i tried that and intercepted the request using a http proxy. the new cookies were not added

Comment: you might consider using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) which has cookie support built-in

Comment: requests is no alternative for me since i need to use proxies. considering the documentation there is no proxy support...

Answer (score 0):

After the application has set the cookies you want, you should do `cj.save( 'cookies.txt' )` to save the current set cookies to that file, and use `cj.load('cookies.txt')` to load them at application start.
See the [cookielib documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib)